# Conditional on route in HTML file issue

Tags: angular, angular7

I found this code for detecting the current route but it does not seem to work in Angular 7.

Here is the code:

app.component.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

...

constructor(private router: Routes) {}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="router.url === '/someroute'">We are in someroute</div>
```

How can I check the route in the .html of a component in NG 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject `Router` instead of `Routes`

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

...

constructor(public router: Router) {}
```

and use it like

```
<div *ngIf="router.url === '/someroute'">We are in someroute</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in the template, you must define it as `public` not `private` and use `ActivatedRoute` instead of `Routes`

so:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

...

constructor(public router: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Url is not available on **Routes**, You have to use **Router**

below is example,

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

and in HTML,

```
<div *ngIf="router.url === '/someroute'">We are in someroute</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`router` must be of type `Router` Not `Routes` and in order to use it in the view template it should be public.

```
    import {  Router } from '@angular/router';
     .
     .
     .
     constructor(public router: Router) { }
```